# Сочетаемость: путешествие по городу

Tags: лексическая-сочетаемость

В очередной заметке встретилось сочетание "путешествовал по городу". Лично мне режет слух. По-моему, путешествовать можно по чему-то большому: стране, краю, Крыму, Азии и т. п. Так имеет ли "путешествие по городу" право на жизнь или я загоняюсь?

Comment: У Вас в последней вопросительной фразе нет противопоставления.

Answer (score 1):

Я думаю, что такое "путешествие" вполне имеет право на существование. Не говоря уж о том, что города тоже бывают весьма немаленькими, сам факт пребывания в другом городе является своего рода путешествием. 
Возможно, если заменить слово "город" на, например, Париж, то это не будет так резать глаз. "Ночное путешествие по Парижу", "Виртуальное путешествие по Праге" и т. д. и т. п.

Answer (score 0):

В принципе, да — по чему-то большому. Но в определенном контексте можно и по городу путешествовать. А то ведь можно дойти до того, что путешествовать можно только пешком (шествие же!)